# Issue occurs after upgrade glassfish 2 to glassfish 3. Unable to locate remote ejb

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, glassfish

I am working on upgrading a systems comprises application that runs on top of application server glassfish from version 2 to 3.1, and its integration and SOAP services. The integrations and services running on top of tomcat 6. After the upgrade of the application, I did the recompilation of the integration and SOAP services source codes using the latest glassfish compatibility jar libraries. The issue occurs when running the SOAP service:

```
        12:05:44,585 ERROR [com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.BOQService] - javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Unable to locate remote ejb: com.visionael.api.vfd.FacilityApiRemote
    javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Unable to locate remote ejb: com.visionael.api.vfd.FacilityApiRemote
        at com.visionael.api.ApiFactoryBase.lookup(ApiFactoryBase.java:126)
        at com.visionael.api.ApiFactory.getFacilityApi(ApiFactory.java:61)
        at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.NRMClient.connect(NRMClient.java:64)
        at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.ContextListener.getNRM(ContextListener.java:44)
        at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.BOQService.getBOQItems(BOQService.java:46)
        at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.NrmBoqSOAPImpl.generateBOQItems(NrmBoqSOAPImpl.java:33)
        at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.NrmBoqSOAPSkeleton.generateBOQItems(NrmBoqSOAPSkeleton.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
12:05:44,586 ERROR [com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.NrmBoqSOAPImpl] - com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.BOQServiceException: 000:Internal error:javax.naming.ConfigurationException-Unable to locate remote ejb: com.visionael.api.vfd.FacilityApiRemote
com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.BOQServiceException: 000:Internal error:javax.naming.ConfigurationException-Unable to locate remote ejb: com.visionael.api.vfd.FacilityApiRemote
    at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.internal.BOQService.getBOQItems(BOQService.java:98)
    at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.NrmBoqSOAPImpl.generateBOQItems(NrmBoqSOAPImpl.java:33)
    at com.ag.neps.nrm_boq.NrmBoqSOAPSkeleton.generateBOQItems(NrmBoqSOAPSkeleton.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Do you know how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: GF 3.1? That's pretty old one, hope you know about it... Could you provide some more details about deployment? How you're building application archive? Is it war, ear or something else? Do you have `beans.xml` file? Did you change anything else in application?

Comment: Actually it is not me the one who developed the services. I just took over the task from the previous developer. It is just some class files deployed to the tomcat directory under webapps. I only provided with the latest jars for it through eclipse to recompilation. Any info you need please let me know.